# problems with jQuery on my Magento website (doesn't seem to be working)

Tags: jquery, magento

I am very new to magento so maybe it's caused by writing my my scripts wrong. 
The template on my magento site runs jQuery and when I test it on my website with if(jQuery) { console.log('jquery'); }
it shows that jQuery is active.
When I try to target an element or class on my webpage ie: $('.some_class') { alert('testing'); }

or any other test i've tried isn't working.

the jQuery and test scripts are located below the css on the page... Just not sure whats causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, Magento is packaged with Prototype, so in order to use jQuery you need to use jQuery.noConflict and reference it with `jQuery` as opposed to `$`. To get around always using `jQuery` or you can wrap all your js code in something like:

```
(function ($){
  // your jquery code - you can use $ in here
})(jQuery);
```